# SUM columns by value in two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table that holds columns for team names (**HomeTeam**, **AwayTeam**) that are strings, then some statistics and then columns **home_points** and **away_points**. I would like to create a query or procedure to sum points of each team and sort it by highest points. The problem is that the team is sometimes HomeTeam and sometimes AwayTeam and corresponds with either home_points or away_points. I guess my knowledge of SQL is not that broad and I failed to find another example of this issue. I tried to do it through some joins, but I still don't understand how to address this problem.
The table looks like this:

```
id   HomeTeam   AwayTeam   home_points   away_points
1    Team1      Team2      3             0
2    Team3      Team1      1             1
3    Team2      Team4      0             3
4    Team1      Team4      0             3
```

And I would like result table to look like:

```
Position   Team    Points
1          Team4     6
2          Team1     4
3          Team3     1
4          Team2     0
```

I've made a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11b2c/2) of the minimal example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a union:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC) Position,
    Team,
    SUM(Points) AS Points
FROM
(
    SELECT HomeTeam AS Team, home_points AS Points FROM matches UNION ALL
    SELECT AwayTeam, away_points FROM matches
) t
GROUP BY
    Team
ORDER BY
    Points DESC;
```

This answer assumes that your are using MySQL 8+ (which will be increasingly likely for any reader of this question in the future).  If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, we can simulate row number with user variables to generate the position you want.  Here is how you can do that:

```
SELECT
    @rn := @rn + 1 AS Position,
    t.Team,
    t.Points
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.Team,
        SUM(t.Points) AS Points
    FROM
    (
        SELECT HomeTeam AS Team, home_points AS Points FROM matches UNION ALL
        SELECT AwayTeam, away_points FROM matches
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        t.Team
) t, (SELECT @rn := 0) r
ORDER BY
    t.Points DESC;
```

[image: screen capture of SQL demo]

### Demo

Comment: That's because `ROW_NUMBER()` is a newer mysql command @BilalSiddiqui

Comment: Mysql finally got the window functions.. yay!!

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui Use my second query in this case, it should work even on your version of MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen second query returns 4,1,2,3 in position, Expected is 1,2,3,4

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui It's (finally) fixed.  If you have long term requirements like this I _strongly_ suggest ditching your outdated version of MySQL and upgrading to MySQL 8+, or use another database with good support for analytic functions.  You can see by the complexity of the second query how much effort it takes to just generate a simple row number sequence (and compare that to the first 8+ version).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am currently running MySQL 5.7, I will make use of your words and update as soon as possible. I am accepting this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . You should put the `order by` in the subquery in the second query.  Using variables with aggregation and order by is tricky.  Often the results need to be materialized for it to work.

Comment: @Gordon Check the demo link, it seems to work there, I'm afraid to change it anymore :-P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The issue is that it might *seem* to work, but either small changes in the query or a different version of MySQL would break it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, it didn't work at all until I materialized the group by query first.